# UICollectionView ReloadData vs ReloadSections

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, ios10, uicollectionviewlayout

When i use `ReloadSection()` it reload the particular sections data and ended up with blinking effect (It adds some alpha and hides). Anyway to hide this effect?

It wont appear when i use `ReloadData()`